Uneven vertical alignment for manual equation numbering
In the following sample, I was wondering why, using manual equation numbering, the equation numbers on the right are not vertically aligned correctly.
Any way to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, label=(\roman*$'$)]
        
        \item $f'_{+} (x^*)(z) \geq 0 \quad \forall \,  z \in T_c (S, x^*).$
        
        \item \hfill%
        $f'_{+} (x^*)(z) \geq 0 \quad \forall \,  z \in T_s (S, x^*).$%
        \hfill\refstepcounter{equation}\textup{(\theequation)}\label{eq:1}
        
        \item \hfill%
        $ \lim\limits_k \inf  f'(x^*) \dfrac{x_k -x^*}{\|x_{k}-x^* \|} \geq 0 $%
        \hfill\refstepcounter{equation}\textup{(\theequation)} \label{eq:2} \\
        whenever $\{x_k\neq x^*\}\subset S$ is a sequence converging to $x^*$.

    \end{enumerate}
    
\end{document}



You have a space before \label{eq:2}. Unrelated, but if you want the “limes inferior” in the second equation, it should be \liminf\limits_k

@egreg: Thank you. That will do it.

I'm not sure about the necessity of a double numbering. Anyway, the problem is the space in front of \label{eq:2}.
I'd use a suitably defined environment for the job.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{enumeq}
 {\hfill$\refstepcounter{equation}\displaystyle}
 {$\hfill\textup{(\theequation)}\par}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, label=(\roman*$'$)]

\item $f'_{+} (x^*)(z) \geq 0 \quad \forall \,  z \in T_c (S, x^*).$

\item \begin{enumeq}\label{eq:f'+}
      f'_{+} (x^*)(z) \geq 0 \quad \forall \,  z \in T_s (S, x^*).
      \end{enumeq}

\item \begin{enumeq}\label{eq:liminf}
      \liminf_k f'(x^*) \dfrac{x_k -x^*}{\|x_{k}-x^* \|} \geq 0
      \end{enumeq}
      whenever $\{x_k\neq x^*\}\subset S$ is a sequence converging to $x^*$.

\end{enumerate}

\eqref{eq:f'+} and \eqref{eq:liminf}
    
\end{document}


